# homographic random variable

Tags: probability

I am working on Galton-Watson processes and I encountered the term "homographic random variables". Although I googled, I could not find anything. Do you have any idea about it? Do you know any book about it?

Comment: Maybe if you copy out the paragraph with the offending term, we could puzzle it out from the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are nonnegative integer random variables $N$ whose generating function $g_N:s\mapsto\mathrm E(s^N)$ is *homographic*, that is, such that $g_N(s)=(as+b)/(cs+d)$ for some parameters $(a,b,c,d)$.